# Flex famous 2048 security violation error, cross domain

Tags: apache-flex, flash, apache, networking

I thought 2048 security violation error were mean to happen when trying to access other domains.

I got:

**"Security sandbox violation: http://127.0.0.1/site_media/main.swf cannot load data from 127.0.0.1:80"**,  isn it the same domain? what is the solution ?

on doing

```
var loader:MultipartLoader = new MultipartLoader("http://127.0.0.1/create/");
```

Did i miss something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite being called "crossdomain" policy files, the policy actually applies to the combination of both the domain and port: localhost:80 and localhost:443 are not the same thing as far as FP's security policy is concerned.  I also don't think that the Flash Player itself assumes a default port of 80 so "localhost" and "localhost:80" are not treated as the same either.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try a relative URL, if Jon Romero's suggestion doesn't work:

```
var loader:MultipartLoader = new MultipartLoader("/create/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using, localhost. If that doesn't work just create a crossdomain file.